# Prove that for every matrix pair $A$ and $B$ exists $C$ such that $B = CA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ are matrix that for every $X$ such that $AX = 0$ also $BX = 0$.

P.S $A$ is from $M(m, n, \mathbb{R})$, $B \in M(k, n, \mathbb{R})$, where $M(a, b, \mathbb{R})$ -- the set of all matrices of size a by b.

The question is to prove that exist some $C \in M(k, m, \mathbb{R})$ such that $B = CA$

In which way I have to think to prove this equality? Seems like we have to say that $b_{ij} \in Lin(A_j)$ -linear shell of $j$-th column from $A$

Comment: What do you mean by "completes"?

Comment: I just fixed it. I mean "If $AX = 0$ then $BX = 0$ also true"

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that the null space (and hence range space) of both matrices have the same dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $BX=O$ for any $X$ such that $AX=O$ tells us $N(A)\subseteq N(B)$ which is equivalent to saying $R(B^T)\subseteq R(A^T)$. For each $j\in \{1,...,k\}$ let $y_j$ denote the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $B^T$. Then $y_j\in R(A^T)$ so $y_j=A^Tx_j$ for some $x_j\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Take $C$ to be the $k\times m$ matrix formed by assigning $x_j$ as its $j^{\text{th}}$ row. Then $A^TC^T=B^T$ which means $CA=B$.

Comment: Can you explain what is $R(A)$ ans $N(A)$?

Comment: The column space is $R(A)$ and the null space is $N(A)$

Comment: Nice and clean answer! Just a minor typo of kth row instead of jth row in the last line.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1. Every row of $B$ is in the row space of $A.$  Then the matrix $C$ just expresses this fact.

Case 2. Some row of $B$ in  not in the row space of $A.$ We denote this row vector by $\mathbf u.$  Let $r$ be the rank of $A.$ Observe that $r\lt n.$ Since we can multiply $A$ on the left by a suitable matrix, we can assume that $A$ is in row reduced echelon form. Form $P$ from  $A$ by putting a column of zeros on the right and then replacing row $r+1$ by $\mathbf u$ followed by $1.$ Let $Q$ be the  rref of $P.$  Let $\lambda$ be the column number of the leading $1$ in row $r+1$ of $Q.$ It is important to understand that $q_{r+1,n+1}$ is nonzero.  Let $X$ be the solution of $AX=O$ defined by setting $x_{\lambda}=q_{r=1,n+1}$ and all remaining parameters to zero. ($x_{\lambda}$ was a parameter for $AX=O$.)
However, $BX$ is nonzero, a contradiction. (If $\mathbf u$ was in row $t$ of $B,$ then the $t$-th component of  $BX$ is $1$.)

Comment: $Q$ is equivalent to $P$ but it is not in rref. Row $r+1$ does not move and 
multiples of it are not added to other rows. All entries of row $r+1$ with leading ones above are made zero in the usual way. After this, a leading one is created by scalar multiplication.